# Django : 'function' object has no attribute 'ModelSelect2'

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, autocomplete

I've been working to make ajax autocomplete. I installed package autocomplete-light and tried to import select2 but failed. it displays error message like this.

error message.

```
 'function' object has no attribute 'ModelSelect2'
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'dal',
'dal_select2',
'dal_queryset_sequence',
```

template.html

```
<form action="{% url 'blog:ajax_article_autocomplete' %}" method="post">
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="id_articles">search: </label>
<input id="id_articles" type="text" size="50" name="articles" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from pip import autocomplete

def ajax_article_autocomplete(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        articles = Article.objects.filter(title__icontains = q )[:10]
        results = []
        for article in articles:
            article_json = {}
            article_json['id'] = article.id
            article_json['label'] = article.title
            article_json['value'] = article.title
            results.append(article_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^ajax/article/autocomplete/$', views.ajax_article_autocomplete, name='ajax_article_autocomplete'),
```

forms.py

```
class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('__all__')
        widgets = {
            'title': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='ajax_tag_autocomplete')
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pip import autocomplete
```

How is this related to the functionality you're trying to add? Pip is the program that installs python packages for you and this is just a utility function.

You're then for some reason trying to get a `ModelSelect2` object from this function?

I think you just messed up your imports and what you want to use is `django_select2.forms.ModelSelect2Widget` (assuming you're using `django-select2`).